# Turbo Debugger вывод значений регистров в двоичном виде

Tags: ассемблер

Можно ли в программе Turbo Debugger сделать вывод значения регистров в двоичном виде, а не в 16-ичном?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нет, отображение только в шест. виде, а вот ввести можно и в двоичном, в конце добавить символ системы, например 0101b